# playframework takes long time to compile code

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

when I change code, it takes at least 5 minutes, then there are some exception thrown on terminal.

I just create a project from "activiator ui" by using play-java-intro.

I am using windows8.1, and java8. CPU is not busy during that period of time.

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
[info] java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:336)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:118)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
[info] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:128)
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:126)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:338)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43)
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the root reason. When starting application, I run activator run, not "bin\activator run".